# How to estimate the sample sized required to achieve a lower p-value in multivariate linear regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

Suppose I obtain a coefficient $\hat{\beta_i}$ and it has 0.01 < p < 0.05. I believe the effect is real so I want to gather more data. Assuming $\hat{\beta_i}$ is close to the correct coefficient, how many more data points are required to obtain p < 0.01?

Comment: A p-value is a random variable, so you can at best calculate the probability Pr(P<0.01). Given the distribution of $\hat{\beta}_i$ this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Knarpie Well we know the normalized coefficient is t-distributed. The problem is that with more samples you’d expect the standard deviation to decrease and the degrees of freedom to go up...so it’s complicated.

Comment: It seems, we're look for the [same](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/437248/209028)